# Memory warning in iPhone Xcode ARC but Instrument doesn't show any leak

Tags: objective-c, didreceivememorywarning

I've completed the coding of my app with ARC Xcode 4.5 but it gives me "Received memory warning.". Because of that I'm not uploading it.

When I test it with instrument it doesn't show any leak but gives low memory warning and after 4-5 warnings the app terminates.

I'm having doubt on some points are in comment.

```
@interface TemplateViewController : UIViewController 
{   
   NSMutableArray *arrNames;       // is this not need to write?
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *arrNames; // is in ARC retain replace by strong ?

@end
```

Or maybe there is other problem?

Answer (score 0):

When you receive memory warning, it does not have necessarily have to be your application fault. If, for any reason, iphone feels that it is out of memory, it broadcasts this message to all the running applications.

As a developer, it is your responsibility to free up some resources so that phone can work normally.

Even if you are not doing anything on receipt of warning, other application might be freeing up some resources so your application can survive even after the warning. At some point of time, it becomes necessary for iphone to terminate all the running applications if it still out of memory.

Check if the same is happening even when your application is not running, if it is so, the culprit is some other application.

Comment: thaks for reply, but if there is no other app running in background then also i received memory warning and app terminate. ithink its becoz of more components allocation.or maybe allocating wrong way?